# dS/CFT in a positive curvature universe

Tags: research-level, ads-cft, holographic-principle, de-sitter-spacetime

Since Maldacena ground breaking theoretical discovery, have there been any succesfull efforts to try to transpose the AdS/CFT duality to our universe (not an AdS)?

Comment: There have been plenty of works in this direction: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/364858/holography-on-non-ads-spacetime?rq=1 and it depends what you consider "succsesfull".